# Windows Server 2012 - Azure Online Backup Status?

Tags: backup, windows-server-2012, azure

What is the current status of Windows Server 2012 Online Backup. All of the documentation provides a start point of [Windows Azure Online Backup](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/features/online-backup/) and tells you to download a software agent.. But at this point (and for the past month), it 404's.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let me Google that for you.

[Oh, it's still in Preview.](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/features/recovery-services/)

You have to enable Preview features manually in your Azure account.

Once logged on, navigate to the Preview Features, or here's the direct URL:

https://account.windowsazure.com/PreviewFeatures

Windows Azure Backup is second in the list and has a "try it now" button on it.

After you hit that button and its enabled for your account, go back to your Portal home page, click Recovery Services on the left side and create a new Backup Vault.

Once your vault is created, go to its settings and behold:

[image]

I followed the agent download link and it was a valid download.

In fact now that I've gone to all this trouble I might actually try it out myself!

Comment: Brilliant. I'm really impressed with how simple you made that "Let me Google that for you" seem. Since I did Google extensively.. The one step I missed was going to `Recovery Services`. Thank Ryan. The service does look pretty promising.

Comment: You're welcome. Sorry if I sounded condescending. My lighthearted yet sardonic sense of humor does not come across very well in writing.  Or in person, for that matter...

Comment: no - it was great! You took us through your process. Thanks again. I'm just finishing the setup.